# Symfony 4 - Default value form not working

Tags: forms, twig, symfony4, default

I have a little problem I don't understand.
I want to display my errors in the same location at the top of the form, I used `form_errors(form)`

Then in my form, I added a default value to my fields.

```
$resolver->setDefaults([
    'data_class' => Whitelist::class,
    'error_bubbling' => true
]);
```

Currently, it does not work and my errors appear in their respective fields.

But if I put this option `'error_bubbling' => true` to my field, it works. Why by default it does not work?

```
->add('firstName', null, [
     'label' => "Prénom de votre personnage",
     'error_bubbling' => true
])
```

Sorry for my english, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`'error_bubbling' => true` means that the error will "bubble" up to the form, where you are trying to display it.

From [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling):

#### error_bubbling

type: boolean default: false unless the form is compound
If true, any errors for this field will be passed to the parent field or form. For example, if set to true on a normal field, any errors for that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific field.

Comment: Yes that's the behavior I want to have.
I may have misunderstood your answer but I want to assign this property to true on all my default fields without having to assign them manually.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. 